# Login a una web desde CURL PHP

Tags: php, curl

saludos ante todo tengo un problema estoy tratando de iniciar session en esta web https://www.freelancer.es pero no logro que funcione el codigo y despues de inciar quiero que valla a la lista de proyectos que esta aca https://www.freelancer.es/search/projects/ me gustaria que me ayudaran y gracias a esta comunidad cada dia aprendemos mas sin nada mas que decir dejo el codigo

```
$username = 'Usuario';
$password = 'Pass';
$loginUrl = 'https://www.freelancer.es/login';

//init curl
$ch = curl_init();


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $loginUrl);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'username='.$username.'&password='.$password);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookie.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

$store = curl_exec($ch);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.freelancer.es/search/projects");
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 0):

Te hace falta información. En primera esa URL no responde al endpoint del login, lo único que tienes es la de login que es muy distinto. la URL es

> https://accounts.freelancer.com.

Pero ahí no termina, los parámetros que estas enviando no son lo que la página pide. Te recomendaría mejor leas su API y trabajar desde ahí

[API Freelancer](https://developers.freelancer.com/docs)

Comment: aca lo tengo pero no lo logro me pide un token https://www.freelancer.es/ajax/auth/login.php